# Oracle - DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_client_info - O que é e quando usar

Tags: oracle

Sobre a linha abaixo em um script PL/SQL

DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_client_info('1111@blabla');

[Entendi](https://eduardolegatti.blogspot.com/2009/05/um-pouco-do-pacote-dbmsapplicationinfo.html) que é um package chamando uma procedure e que ele seta informações do cliente na sessão (no meu caso é a matrícula da coordenadora do faturamento)

No caso, ele vai colocar na tabela como se ela tivesse feito a operação do script? Podem dar mais informações sobre como isso funciona? No Output não aparece nada, não entendi onde ele seta e por que o matricula@empresa

Answer (score 1):

A função [set_client_info](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm#i996826) adiciona a informação no campo Client_Info da view V$SESSION, segundo a documentaçao do oracle este campo é para descrever a aplicação que esta conectada. Teria que ver se sua aplicação utiliza o campo em algum lugar ou se seria apenas para controle do DBA.